# Deploying a private DAAS?

Tags: virtualization, cloud

I am an electronics student who is doing an internship at a Data center. (have small to no knowledge about virtualization, cloud, computer networks).

My friend and I were given a chance to deploy and wire 3 servers. We had the chance to keep one for testing and learning. We tried many virtualization solutions such as Proxmoxx, Openstack and Hyper-V.

Now we're being told to try and deploy a DAAS (Desktop As A Service). I searched online about it but there's nothing about deploying a private DAAS.

So can anyone please confirm if it's possible? (not sure if the guy knows what he's doing)

Thanks in advance

Comment: DAAS as in *Desktop As A Service*? Did the person who gave you the acronym tell you what it *meant*?

Comment: All these f'ing buzzwords...

Comment: @pauska there's nothing wrong with using FTP to deploy a DAAS in the CLOUD.

Comment: Yeah as in Desktop As A Service.
So how can this be done?

Comment: `"not sure if the guy knows what he's doing"` - you sure you want to be throwing that around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"DaaS" is basically VDI with usage chargeback to whoever is the consumer of the desktop resources. Doing this with a single server is likely not possible or will be very ugly. You should be looking at Microsoft RDS VDI pools, VMware Horizon View, or Citrix VDI options as far as enterprise platforms go. You can likely roll your own with other solutions as well.

Again, given your resources and apparent knowledge on the topic, this may be a monster out undertaking.

Answer (score 4):

I know you are a student, but since you are work as an intern I'll be kind and post an answer as opposed to voting to close it as "non-professional", but honestly it still might close.

Private LAN - Desktop As A Service...as in Remote Desktop/Terminal Server or Citrix or VDI?

The entire "AAS" (as a service) acronym is because you are offering it to CUSTOMERS as a PAID SERVICE.  An internal/private solution won't use that acronym unless you just feel like it.

Comment: Alright thanks. Yeah I get that part thanks for clarifying. I think he means Remote Desktop/Terminal for the personnel. I guess he doesn't know what he's doing.